# Is the order of loading of Qt Quick children specified?

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2, order-of-execution

E.g. is it guaranteed that the order of initialization of children matches the order in which they appear in the source code?

Note: by "initialization of a child" I mean "initialization of the child and all its children, descendants, bindings, etc".

Comment: It's a tree, objects are created in order. For bindings, there are no guarantees, the order is arbitrary. It happens on a separate pass, and it can take multiple passes depending on the expression hierarchy. As a rule of thumb, you should not rely on any finer grain than an entire QML file at the root object. If you want tighter control over the order, instantiate the tree imperatively.

Comment: @dtech: "objects are created in order." - but *what* order? :)

Comment: The order of the tree naturally, root to top leaf. I don't know the particular implementation, but common logic dictates you iterate the tree and create every object, pushing and popping the current branch object to be used as a parent. It is highly unlikely that children are created before the parent, then the parent is created, and then you go back to parent all the children...

Comment: @dtech: I'm specifically interested in the case where I have 2 siblings, defined one after the other in the source code. In what order will they be initialized?

Comment: So far from top to bottom, but I don't remember any documentation regarding it. So maybe it might change for the next version and they create them in a random order.

Comment: Assuming the following structure A { B { C {} D {} } E {} }, the objects will be created in that order. First is the root A, then its child B, then B's children C and D, and finally E. Again, no guarantee, just common sense in doing it the most efficient and straightforward way. That's just creation thou. Hooking up binding expressions can easily result in a tangled web.

Comment: They don't give a guarantee of order for `onCompleted`either, but if you test it, you will get a very consistent `E D C B A` output, indicating that it indeed happens in order. It goes out backwards, because the root is not considered completed before all children are completed.

Comment: There might be differences, if you have something like: `property Item a: A {}`, `property Item a: id_a; A{ id: id_a}`, `property Item a: someComp.createObject(root)` or just `A {}` especially when you reference some of those objects early. See: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-60746

Comment: @dtech: Thanks. Well, I see how that might be common sense, but I'm asking for a reliable reference on this.

Comment: @StefanMonov sure thing, knock yourself out: http://code.qt.io/cgit/ ;)

Answer (score 7):

A simple test can be used to verify the order of object creation.

```
class Test : public QQuickItem {
    Q_OBJECT
  public:
    Test(QQuickItem * p = 0) : QQuickItem(p) { qDebug() << this; }
};
```

Then:

```
  Test {
    objectName: "a"
    Component.onCompleted: console.log(objectName, this)
    Test {
      objectName: "b"
      Component.onCompleted: console.log(objectName, this)
      Test {
        objectName: "c"
        Component.onCompleted: console.log(objectName, this)
      }
      Test {
        objectName: "d"
        Component.onCompleted: console.log(objectName, this)
      }
    }
    Test {
      objectName: "e"
      Component.onCompleted: console.log(objectName, this)
    }
  }
```

Which gives the output of:

```
Test(0x6a7378, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
Test(0x6a73d8, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
Test(0x6a7438, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
Test(0x6a7498, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
Test(0x6a74f8, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
qml: a Test(0x6a7378, "a")
qml: e Test(0x6a74f8, "e")
qml: b Test(0x6a73d8, "b")
qml: d Test(0x6a7498, "d")
qml: c Test(0x6a7438, "c")
```

Which indicates that object constructors are indeed called bottom to top.

Also note that the order of `onCompleted` is different, depending on where that handler is installed. If you wrap `Test` in an `Obj.qml` like this:

```
Test {
  id: rectangle
  Component.onCompleted: console.log(objectName, this)
}
```

And declare the structure like this:

```
  Obj {
    objectName: "a"
    Obj {
      objectName: "b"
      Obj {
        objectName: "c"
      }
      Obj {
        objectName: "d"
      }
    }
    Obj {
      objectName: "e"
    }
  }
```

Then you get a consistent "back to front" output which you didn't get in the first scenario:

```
Test(0x4b2458, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
Test(0x4b24b8, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
Test(0x4b2518, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
Test(0x4b2578, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
Test(0x50f9d68, parent=0x0, geometry=0,0 0x0)
qml: e Test(0x50f9d68, "e")
qml: d Test(0x4b2578, "d")
qml: c Test(0x4b2518, "c")
qml: b Test(0x4b24b8, "b")
qml: a Test(0x4b2458, "a")
```

However, all this reflects the order of object creation, not object completion, which involves a bunch of other stuff, which can be executed in an arbitrary order, depending on the binding expression structure.

In short, you shouldn't really be depending on that order, if you do, you are doing it wrong. You should not depend on anything any finer than the entire QML source tree completion, the qtquick engine itself will take care to delay **initialization** of binding expressions and such until the entire object tree is completed, so you won't have a problem with that, it happens automatically, but relying on anything that is lower level and finer grained is a potential flaw in the design and to be avoided. Give your objects ids, and execute one single initialization expression for the entire qml file that hooks up stuff together if you want more explicit order of **initialization**. The statements in that expression will be executed in the order they are defined.

Comment: *[...] you shouldn't really be depending on that order[...]* That order becomes interesting when someone forgot to expose children through properties and you need to access those children by `children[index]` as they are appended to this list in order of creation (unless they are reparented later, that is) - So if you want to style `QtQuick.Controls 1.x`-Objects it is always nice that you can go to the source code to easily determine on which position in this list you will find the part where you want to change a property.

Comment: This is not considered a "stable" interface, I personally wouldn't do that. That order might change for a number of reasons. I'd rather copy the control source and interface the stuff that I need.

Comment: I would consider it a stable interface as, as far as I know it is not maintained anymore, so changes are unlikely. So let's say: stable enough.

Comment: It is not only source code changes that can result in children index change. Creation and deletion of children can change that during the runtime. Naturally, there might be scenarios where it is sufficiently safe, but overall, I would not recommend the practice.

Comment: Ok, you won. Of course it is never good practice to rely on private implementation details.